# Which of these are convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus

Decide which of the following sequences are convergent or divergent? Find the limit if it exists.

( I think the first one rotates from $1$ and $-1$ so would be divergent and the second one just rotates from being $0$ and $1$ ).
$$
\begin{array}{rrcl}
a)& x_{k} & = & \left(\,-1\,\right)^{k^{2}} + {1 \over k^{3}}
\\[2mm]
b)& x_{k + 1} & = &  1 - x_{k}^{2}\,,\qquad\qquad x_{1} = 1
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to notice that $x_k = (-1)^{k^2}+\frac{1}{k^3}$ gets closer to  $-1$ and $1$ in an alternating fashion (because the $\frac{1}{k^3}$ term approaches zero), but it is wrong to use the word *converges*. If a sequence alternates between two values like this, then we consider the sequence to be *divergent* (it needs to approach only a single value to be *convergent*).

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean the second one diverges as well since it simply rotates between 0 and 1

Comment: @Nick That is correct. Also, check out [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) link so you can make your mathematics look nicer when posting questions. It definitely helps the reader (especially when the notation starts to get more complicated).

Answer (score 1):

The first one indeed *has no limit* because of the reason you mention.

The second sequence's first terms are:

$$x_1=1\,,\,x_2=1-1^2=0\,,\,x_3=1-0^2=1\,,\,x^4=1-1^1=0\;,\ldots$$

It's easy to show (e.g., induction), that this sequence is $\;\{1,0,1,0,1,0,\ldots\}\;$ , and thus it also has no limit.